# Can Apache serve a default file instead of a 404?

Tags: apache, http-status-code-404

We have Apache serving a set of files from a particular directory. If a file requested in that directory does not exist, can I make Apache return a default file - instead of a 404? If so, how?

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved making use of .htaccess.

Check [this WebReference article on the topic](http://www.webreference.com/programming/apache_errors/).

Basically you only need a file name .htaccess in your directory which contains

```
ErrorDocument 404 /YourCustomErrorPage.html
```

Of course any other file can be served too.

Comment: This is still a 404, only with different content.

Answer (score 2):

What kind of file? Is it a static file? With Apache you can set [custom error pages](http://www.webreference.com/programming/apache_errors/).

Comment: "custom error pages" is a dead link now.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful returning non-404s for any random URI request. It may impact your Google rankings if they notice it and consider it part of a link farm or other such blackhat SEO technique.

Comment: +1 for being interesting and relevant but in my personal experience I've never seen Google slammer my sites for random 404's. Has it happened to anyone?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return a file successfully **instead of** with a 404 status, you can use the [`FallbackResource` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource) instead of `ErrorDocument`.

```
FallbackResource /YourCustomDocument.html
```

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this. It is of great help in handling complicated URL rewriting in PHP instead of trying to use the Apache rewrite directives, which have no way to do debugging.