# how to aviod default break image icon if an image is not loaded from a file?

Tags: image, internet-explorer, google-chrome, cross-browser

I have used a  tag with attribute src="mydirectory/myimage.gif.

If the image is not present in the directory , how can i avoid showing a default break image inside my img tag ?

this is present in chrome and I.E browsers but not in Firefox...

Any idea to avoid this ?

Thank You ...

Comment: I don't think there is a way to change this behaviour. You would have to check images for their existence beforehand, or use JavaScript's `onerror`  event to hide failed image tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A popular way to do it is to edit your web server.

for example, on apache, if you store all your images in a directory "http://host/images",
and add a .htaccess file to that directory to redirect all 404s to serve a default blank image.

see here:
[Can Apache serve a default file instead of a 404?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674603/can-apache-serve-a-default-file-instead-of-a-404)
but you are serving an image instead of any kind of file.

There are other ways of doing it, for example, if you have access to a server side language (php, ruby) you can check if an image file exists on your server first, if not, serve a default image.

Or use the javascript method as mentioned by Pekka.

You can do it with your web server, server side / client side script.

I dont know if there's a way to do it with CSS, or other techniques, sure others will fill in.

Hope that is helpful.

Comment: Thank u very much Winfred & Pekka .. I have used javascript onerror method to solve this problem. I have already used server side handling method of loading a default image.. in some cases you don't want to load a default image for the user .. so , i choose javascript for solving this case ..

Comment: if you are using server side handling, you can use a 1px blank image as your default image for some images.